# Job going to be terminated?

Tags: job-search, freelancing

I have started a job as an independent consultant a couple of months now.

The pay is good and I have been learning new stuff more than producing.

However, my colleague, who is in a similar situation, told me that he noticed terminating signs.

One big reason he is worrying, is related to the fact that, generally, freelancers don't accept 3 months missions.

So we were hired on the basis that the duration is beyond a year.

During the interview, they asserted that this job would take more than a year.

Last week, the manager contacted us and asked if we were up to work on a different kind of tasks.

It was an occasion for me to ask if I was going to work on a different project.

The manager sounded worrying, and said that it's a different kind of tasks, and asked "why would you think you would not be in the same project"?

I just told me him I heard there are new projects yet to come, and they can't easily new resources.

He said "don't worry, we will not let you leave".

We had a discussion today, and my colleague again told me he feels like the contract will be terminated November, and we are only finalizing the work.

We tried to us the manager in a subtle way, and he told us that he is waiting for input from other teams, that's why there are not too many tasks for now.

He affirmed he got the budget for this year and next year.

Is my colleague right?

Is the manager hiding something?

Should I start a new job hunt?

Comment: Neither can we magically determine whether your boss was lying (or whether he is convinced of what he says, but it will turn out differently anyway), nor can we make decisions for you. However, if you are looking for job security, "independent contractor" would probably be the opposite of that.

Answer (score 5):

> Is my colleague right? Is the manager hiding something?

No way to know.

> Should I start a new job hunt?

An independent consultant should always be looking ahead for the next gig. That involves some professional networking, and making it known when you will become available to work.

That said, you have a contract for a certain period of time. As that time approaches, start to find your next contract - either with this company, or another.

Answer (score 3):

*"Don't* ***borrow*** *trouble."*

If you ever have the misfortune of *becoming* "a manager" ...  ... you will then "instantly understand."

Just keep the lines of communication wide-open with your manager.  Instead of "worrying yourself to death," ***"ask."***

Because: when you ask, you deal the cards back into the manager's deck.  He now is aware of them, and he can respond.  Very likely, he knows (many) things that you don't – including things that really don't directly concern you.  Therefore, enable your manager to do his/her job.  Believe it or not, you are all on the same team.

*Full disclosure:* "Here's what a manager in such a position fears the very most – *a bolt out of the blue."*  Turns out that employees have been harboring fears that you never even knew about, because they were afraid to ask, **and they just jumped ship.** Now you've got a boatload of problems without warning. *("Ask me how I know ...")*

Comment: +1 for "don't borrow trouble"  My favorite phrase